# Finding and uninstalling PIL on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I want to install Pillow and have read in many places this only works if PIL is removed.

Somewhere I have PIL installed but I am unable to find it or remember how it was installed. I'm pretty much a ctrl+c and ctrl+v guy when it comes to installing things through terminal, so I imagine I had some trouble installing it in the first place.

I have tried

```
pip uninstall PIL
easy_install uninstall PIL
brew uninstall PIL
```

and run out of ideas. I can't even find any file with name "PIL" with spotlight.

Just want to find a way to get rid of PIL and install Pillow so I can add text to a few hundred images.

Running python 2.7 on El Capitan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find where PIL is located on your machine, use Python to import it and have it print out its location:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__file__
```

On my system, this gives:

```
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.pyc'
```

From this you can see where your `site-packages` directory is located. Now exit python, go into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` (your exact path may differ from mine) and delete the folder `PIL`. That should get rid of it.

```
 cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
 sudo rm -rf PIL
```